# In Razor EditorFor template prevent rendering a default value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In my `Razor view`. I have markup like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Principal, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Principal)
    </div>
</div>
```

Principal has the Required data annotation, so my `html` is rendered as so:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Principal must be a number." data-val-required="The Principal field is required." id="Principal" name="Principal" type="text" value="0.00">
```

I want exactly this behavior just without the default value. Is there any way to do this without creating my own editor template?

Principal is a decimal. Making it nullable is not an option in this case, I want to force the user to input a valid number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that Principle is a decimal type in your model.  Decimal types are value types and non-nullable, thus .net must always assign a value.  If you don't, it assigns the default.

If you don't want the default, you must make the property nullable.

Comment: It is a decimal value. Making it nullable is not an option due to other constraints

Comment: @BrendanMcKee - How do you intend to make a non-nullable value not contain a value then?  Magic?

Comment: I want the form to be empty and force the user to input something. If they don't and post it, it will return an error message

Comment: @BrendanMcKee - If you're using a view model like you should, there should be no reason why you can't make the value nullable.  That's why view models exist, to differentiate your views requirements from your domains requirements.

Comment: Yep that's my problem, I use view models elsewhere but I haven't here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is One way through `Jquery`.  In  your model `no need` to make `property nullable`.

Just re-assign the value through `Jquery` if your `Textbox` is having default value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if($('#Principle ').val() == '0.00' || $('#Principle ').val() == '0')
   {
       $('#Principle ').val('');
   }
});
```

This will be triggered when the page is once ready / Completed the loading.

As you know .Net Framework default value will be assigned when if you don't assign the value for the `Value Types`.